# How to parse a page after n amount of time, with blocking parsing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I need to reparse a page after some amount of time. To do this I do:

```
c = CallLaterOnce(spider.crawler.engine.schedule,{
                    'retryreq': retryreq,
                    'spider': spider
})
c.schedule(delay=40)
```

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_modules/scrapy/utils/reactor.html?highlight=CallLaterOnce

It uses `reactor.callLater(delay, self)`. The problem is that scrapy doesn't wait all reactor tasks to be done. So scrapy exits before adding parsing a page to the queue `spider.crawler.engine.schedule`. As far as understand need some way to "block it" until all reactor tasks are done.